# Why would PDF Text extraction hang for a single PDF but work via RDP

Tags: windows, pdf, fonts, tesseract, remote-desktop

I have a program that extracts text from PDFs.  It runs as a scheduled task on Windows Server 2008.

The library I use is ByteScout's PDF Extractor SDK, which is based on Tesseract under the covers.

Since it went live last November, the program has successfully extracted text from over 50,000 PDFs from many different sources.

It recently hung on a single PDF and subsequently on a second one, from the same source in the same visual format.

I am able to recreate the problem using a trivial 12 line program.  I sent this program to the vendor but running that program in their environment works (it does not hang).

So I did some experimentation and this is where it gets strange.

The program works on my PC (Windows 7) if I RDP to it, but not if I am directly logged in. This behavior is repeated on other Windows 7 PCs in our environment.

It works on Server 2008 if I am RDPed, but not as a scheduled task.

It works on Windows 10, whether I am RDPed or logged in directly.

If I watch the program in Process Monitor when it is stuck, I can see that it is opening and reading C:\Windows\Fonts\times.ttf over and over again.

If it was only working using RDP, I'd wonder if the cause had anything to do with failing use of graphics acceleration or some such, but given that it doesn't work as a scheduled task where none would be present either, I think that's a blind alley.

Does anyone have any suggestions where to look next?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So ByteScout have fixed the problem.  To quote Eugene on the cause ...

> The problem is in System.Drawing and GDI+. Sometimes it crashes on text drawing operations that are normal in PDF but causing some internal exceptions in System.Drawing. Moreover, it's behavior varies depending on display device capabilities. That is why it works in RDP session and crashes on a desktop.
>   We are trying various workarounds on these crashes, attempting to fall back to alternate text drawing ways. The hanging is related to these fallbacks.